# How to combine three lines into one, separated by comma

Tags: text-formatting

How to turn this text:

```
                                             From: "anonymous" <sip:anonymous@test.com>;tag=1c1969267918
                                             Call-ID: 3227998302912020104951@192.168.1.10
                                             Max-Forwards: 70
                                             From: "anonymous" <sip:anonymous@test.com>;tag=1c6447025742
                                             Call-ID: 1426914846291202010505@192.168.1.10
                                             Max-Forwards: 70
```

Into this one:

```
From: "anonymous" <sip:anonymous@test.com>;tag=1c1969267918, Call-ID: 3227998302912020104951@192.168.1.10, Max-Forwards: 70
From: "anonymous" <sip:anonymous@test.com>;tag=1c6447025742, Call-ID: 1426914846291202010505@192.168.1.10, Max-Forwards: 70
```

Comment: have you looked at your post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless the single space after the commas in your expected output are very important:

```
$ sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//' file | paste -d, - - -
From: "anonymous" <sip:anonymous@test.com>;tag=1c1969267918,Call-ID: 3227998302912020104951@192.168.1.10,Max-Forwards: 70
From: "anonymous" <sip:anonymous@test.com>;tag=1c6447025742,Call-ID: 1426914846291202010505@192.168.1.10,Max-Forwards: 70
```

This first uses `sed` to remove the initial whitespace on each line in the input file, and then distributes the resulting lines, using `paste`, across three columns with commas as delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{sub(/^[[:blank:]]*/, ""); ORS = NR % 3 ? ", " : "\n"; print}' < your-file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in shell:

```
n=0
while read x; do
    echo -n "$x"
    n=$((n+1))
    if [ $((n%3)) = 0 ]; then
        echo
    else
        echo -n ', '
    fi
 done < inputfile
```

This read lines one by one, and keeps count. Every 3rd line (the `$((n%3))` part calculates the modulus) a newline is output, otherwise the comma (and space as per your example) is output. The `echo -n` prevents `echo` adding a newline itself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can be done more nicely. But it works fine.

gnu sed:
First expression removes leading spaces.
Second expression joins the following line matching `/From:/` and removes leading spaces.
Second expression joins the following line matching `/Call-ID:/` and removes leading spaces.

```
sed -e 's/^[[:blank:]]*//' \
    -e  '/From:/N;s/\n[[:blank:]]*/, /' \
    -e  '/Call-ID:/N;s/\n[[:blank:]]*/, /'
```